# Installing Multitail on RHEL 5.3

Tags: linux, yum, tail

I'm trying to install Multitail on a RHEL 5.3 machine, but get the following error as the root user.  Should this be accessible from one of the default RPM repositories or do I need to add a new repository or update an existing repository perhaps?

```
18:01:04 # yum install multitail
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package multitail available.
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 2):

`multitail` for RHEL5 is only available in the EPEL (Extended Packages for Enterprise Linux) Red Hat repository. To learn more about EPEL packages, see the [How can I use these extra packages?](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) Fedora webpage.